# How to compare sourceItem.userInfo and domainUserInfo in FileProvider extension ActivationRule?

Tags: swift, macos, fileprovider, fileprovider-extension

I'm creating a Rename-forbidden `NSFileProviderUserInteractions` rule.

My goal: if `sourceItem` owner is not currently logged-in user, Rename should be forbidden.

User-interaction rule in *Info.plist* file:

```
<dict>
  <key>ActivationRule</key>
  <string>action == &quot;Rename&quot; AND sourceItem.userInfo.owner != domainUserInfo.user</string>
  <key>SubInteractions</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>ActivationRule</key>
      <string>TRUEPREDICATE</string>
      <key>Alert</key>
      <dict>
        <key>LocalizedRecoveryOptions</key>
        <dict>
          <key>Cancel</key>
          <string>OK</string>
        </dict>
        <key>LocalizedSubTitle</key>
        <string>Only owners can rename items.</string>
        <key>LocalizedTitle</key>
        <string>Forbidden action</string>
        <key>RecoveryOptions</key>
        <dict>
          <key>Continue</key>
          <false/>
        </dict>
      </dict>
    </dict>
  </array>
</dict>
```

It smells like comparing

```
sourceItem.userInfo.owner != domainUserInfo.user
```

doesn't seem to work.

I also see an error in console:

```
[ERROR] User interaction  is not a dictionary
```

If, on the other hand I hard-code the *ActivationRule* like:

```
<key>ActivationRule</key>
<string>action == &quot;Rename&quot; AND sourceItem.userInfo.owner != "current_user_id"</string>
```

then the behavior is correct (Rename is forbidden only for items not belonging to current user).

Is there a way to compare `sourceItem.userInfo` and `domainUserInfo` in *ActivationRule* predicate?

Comment: What helped was to move the rename-allowed logic to `userInfo` in `FileProviderItem` so now my `ActivationRule`is `action == "Rename" AND sourceItem.userInfo.renameForbidden == true`. However still, for root-level items, userInfo is often not invoked until I open the item in the Finder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the problem seemed to be elsewhere: I didn't properly set the collection owner in `FileProviderEnumerator.enumerateItems()` method. Once I fixed that, things started working smoothly.

Closing as resolved.